# Eclipse goes to maven local repo copy of a project, even though that project exists on the workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

Using M2Eclipse plugin. Project A depends on Project B. Project B exists both in maven local repository and on workspace. While debugging, Eclipse ignores the workspace copy and goes to maven local repository copy of Project B.

But the weird thing is, when I remove Project B from the `pom.xml` of Project A, Eclipse goes to workspace copy.

I have tried:

- Disabling workspace resolution of Project A and re-enabling it.
- Clean installing Project A and Project B.
- Force updating Project A.

Neither of these worked. When I remove Project B from `pom.xml` of Project A, it works. When I re-add Project B to the `pom.xml` of Project A, Eclipse goes to maven local repo copy of Project B again. But removing Project B from the list of dependencies of Project A is obviously not the way to go.

Did anyone else observed this weird behavior? What should I do to stop this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Within Eclipse, you can add, in the dependent project (Project A), a link to your **workspace project** (Project B), instead of the one inside your Maven local repo.

You have to do this on the dependent project (project A): 
`Right click > Build path > Configure Build path...` and in the `Projects` tab, you add your **workspace project**.

Comment: But shouldn't `m2e` be handling this?

Comment: Yes, but sometimes, it just fails to do it properly. So you have to do it manually

Comment: I found it. Apparently, someone has changed the version of Project B dependency on Project A's `pom.xml` from `TEST-SNAPSHOT` to `UAT-SNAPSHOT`. Since the version of Project B on my workspace is `TEST-SNAPSHOT`, Eclipse naturally thinks that this is not the version it is looking for, and hence, it goes to maven local repository.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Apparently, someone has changed the version of Project B dependency on Project A's `pom.xml` from `TEST-SNAPSHOT` to `UAT-SNAPSHOT`. Since the version of Project B on my workspace is `TEST-SNAPSHOT`, Eclipse naturally thinks that this is not the version it is looking for, and hence, it goes to maven local repository.

In other words, Project A's `pom.xml` changed from this:

```
... 
<dependency>
            <groupId>SomeGroupID</groupId>
            <artifactId>Project_B</artifactId>
            <version>TEST-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
...
```

to this:

```
... 
<dependency>
            <groupId>SomeGroupID</groupId>
            <artifactId>Project_B</artifactId>
            <version>UAT-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
...
```

And this is the `pom.xml` of the Project B in my workspace:

```
...
<groupId>SomeGroupID</groupId>
<artifactId>Project_B</artifactId>
<version>TEST-SNAPSHOT</version>
...
```

Since Project A references `UAT-SNAPSHOT` version of Project B (instead of `TEST-SNAPHOT` version), Eclipse naturally thinks that Project B in my workspace is not the project which Project A is looking for. Hence, Eclipse goes to my local maven repository.

Take home message is, one should check very carefully that the version being referenced, and the version of the project which you expect to be referenced matches exactly.